# Не работает форматировщик под PEP-8 на Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Вопрос выше. Недавно перешел с Python 3.9.13 64-bit на Python 3.10.0 64-bit и перестал работать форматировщик. Сижу на VS Code. Проверил настройки все включено и сделано.
Причем если отформатировать файл сочетанием клавиш **ctrl+shift+f** на 3.9.13, а потом перейти на 3.10.0 то форматировщик уже ничего не делает, но сообщение в статус бар выводит
**Formatting with autopep8**. Что делать без понятия, надоело туда-сюда переключаться между версиями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На всякий случай: PEP-8 не может "не работать" - это документ. Поправил название, а то непонятно было, о чём речь.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: От версии Python не зависит,  это могут быть только настройки  Вашей среды разработки.

Comment: так, а почему на одной версии работает, а на другой нет значит дело все таки в версии? @VasilijsLaskovskis

Comment: Один вопрос. Нафига 3.10.0 когда актуальная 3.10.5?

Comment: Нужные библиотеки работают на 3.10 @Namerek

Comment: И эти нужные библиотеки не запускаются на 3.10.5 что ли?

Comment: не проверял @andreymal

Comment: только что обновил 3.10.0 до 3.10.5 и форматировщик все равно не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

разобрался в чем была проблема. в 3.10.0 не был установлен autopep8 а 3.9.13 он был.
-m pip install -U autopep